# AngularJS send id of selectbox

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

This is my selectbox:

```
<data-ui-select data-ng-model="$parent.car" data-ng-disabled="!car" data-ng-change="update_car()">
 <data-ui-select-match placeholder="Cars">{{$select.selected.name}}</data-ui-select-match>
   <data-ui-select-choices repeat="item in car_select | filter: $select.search">
     <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
   </data-ui-select-choices>
</data-ui-select>
```

And this is my model:

```
{"id":1,"name":"bmw"}
```

When I select an option it returns the name instead of the ID, what can I do to get the ID?

Thanks,

EDIT: Plunker with an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/9Kn9kP4qJ5mzPOqyFiHF?p=preview

Comment: could you put your code on jsfiddle please?

Comment: Then it should be `ng-bind-html="item.id ..`

Comment: Plunker with an example http://plnkr.co/edit/9Kn9kP4qJ5mzPOqyFiHF?p=preview